# Perl LWP::UserAgent mishandling UTF-8 response

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

When I use LWP::UserAgent to retrieve content encoded in UTF-8 it seems LWP::UserAgent doesn't handle the encoding correctly.

Here's the output after setting the Command Prompt window to Unicode by the command `chcp 65001` Note that this initially gives the appearance that all is well, but I think it's just the shell reassembling bytes and decoding UTF-8, From the other output you can see that perl itself is not handling wide characters correctly.

```
C:\>perl getutf8.pl
======================================================================
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 31 Dec 2010 19:24:04 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6
Content-Length: 75
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Dec 2010 19:20:18 GMT
Client-Date: Fri, 31 Dec 2010 19:24:04 GMT
Client-Peer: 127.0.0.1:80
Client-Response-Num: 1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name>Budějovický Budvar</name>

======================================================================
response content length is 33

....v....1....v....2....v....3....v....4
<name>Budějovický Budvar</name>

. . . . v . . . . 1 . . . . v . . . . 2 . . . . v . . . . 3 . . . .
3c6e616d653e427564c49b6a6f7669636bc3bd204275647661723c2f6e616d653e
< n a m e > B u d � � j o v i c k � �   B u d v a r < / n a m e >
```

Above you can see the payload length is 31 characters but Perl thinks it is 33.
For confirmation, in the hex, we can see that the UTF-8 sequences c49b and c3bd are being interpreted as four separate characters and not as two Unicode characters.

Here's the code

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->get('http://localhost/Bud.xml');
if (! $response->is_success) { die $response->status_line; }

print '='x70,"\n",$response->as_string(), '='x70,"\n";

my $r = $response->decoded_content((charset => 'UTF-8')); 
$/ = "\x0d\x0a"; # seems to be \x0a otherwise!
chomp($r);

# Remove any xml prologue
$r =~ s/^<\?.*\?>\x0d\x0a//;

print "Response content length is ", length($r), "\n\n";
print "....v....1....v....2....v....3....v....4\n";
print $r,"\n";

print ". . . . v . . . . 1 . . . . v . . . . 2 . . . . v . . . . 3 . . . . \n";
print unpack("H*", $r), "\n";
print join(" ", split("", $r)), "\n";
```

Note that Bud.xml is UTF-8 encoded without a BOM.

**How can I persuade LWP::UserAgent to do the right thing?**

*P.S. Ultimately I want to translate the Unicode data into an ASCII encoding, even if it means replacing each non-ASCII character with **one** question mark or other marker.*

---

#### Update 1

I have accepted Ysth's "upgrade" answer - because I know it is the right thing to do when possible. However there is a work around to fix up the data into a well formed Perl Unicode string.

```
$r = decode("utf8", $r);
```

---

#### Update 2

My data gets fed to a non-Perl application that displays the data using Code Page 437 to Putty/Reflection/Teraterm terminals at many locations. The app is currently displaying something like:

```
Bud├ä┬øjovick├â┬¢ Budvar
```

I am going to use `($r = decode("UTF-8", $r)) =~ s/[\x80-\x{FFFF}]/\xFE/g;` to get the app to display:

```
Bud■jovick■ Budvar
```

Moving away from CP437 would be a major job, so that is not going to happen in the short to medium term.

---

#### Update 3

CPAN has some interesting Unicode modules such as:

- Text::Unidecode
- Unicode::Map8
- Unicode::Map
- Unicode::Escape
- Unicode::Transliterate

Text::Unidecode translated "Budějovický Budvar" into "Budejovicky Budvar" - which didn't seem to me a particularly impressive attempt at a phonetic transliteration but then I don't speak Czech. English speakers might prefer it to "Bud■jovick■ Budvar" though.

Comment: for sanity checking, what version of LWP are you using?

Comment: @ysth LWP::UserAgent version 2.036, LWP version 5.808

Comment: Your stated ultimate goal of translating 21-bit Unicode data into 7-bit ASCII data is depressing, because I’ve myself just gone to no small amount of trouble to homogenize ~100k documents into Unicode. Out of 11,542 documents, 10,997 were in UTF-8 (95.39%), 539 were in ISO-8859-1 (4.67%), 5 were in Shift_JIS (0.04%), and 1 alone was in Windows-1252 (0.0087%). You want to converge upon 21-bit characters, not on 7-bit characters!  Welcome to the New Millennium, whose second decade is about to start in less than 5 hours.

Comment: Another problem with unicastrating into things with `?`’s in them is that this particular action is **very** *specifically advised against* in the standards documents. You cannot tell a valid `?` from an invalid one. The C0 control codes might be useful here. Character 1A is the SUBSTITUTION character, which works in ASCII much as the U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER works in Unicode. 1A was for “Originally intended for use as a transmission control character to indicate that garbled or invalid character had been received.” U+FFFD now does that duty for us. Please don’t unicastrate your data.

Comment: @tchrist: see updates at end of question, I think the last is marginally better. Putty ignores \x1A so I'm using \xFE (■) since I feel it better to give some visual indication of a missing character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer libwwwperl.  The old version you are using only honored the charset argument to decoded_content for text/* content types; the newer version also does so for application/xml or anything ending +xml.